# Configure HTTPS on server over HTTPS in application

Tags: asp.net, spring-boot, tomcat, iis, https

I could not find any similiar questions.
**What means to enable HTTPS on server versus in application directly, what is the difference between the two and what is better** ?

For example: If you have a Spring Boot application running on Tomcat server, you can configure HTTPS directly in Spring Boot (keystore, application properties), or on Tomcat server itself.
In both cases, Application would be served over HTTPS?

Do they need to go in pair, or just one of them is enough?
Question should be the same for other combinations as well: Asp.Net and IIS, PHP and WAMP etc.

Comment: "Spring framework" can configure ssl for you (via properties or xml) or you can do it from within the code.  In both cases, application would be served over HTTPS. One of them is enough i think.

Comment: "Question should be the same for other combinations as well" is completely wrong. IIS/ASP.NET only allows you to set HTTPS on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP connections are managed by a web server like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html). Spring Boot doesn't handle them directly. The difference between configuring HTTPS in Spring Boot rather than in Tomcat is a matter of how your application is packaged.

A Spring Boot application can be packaged as a WAR artifact and deployed on an external Tomcat server. In this case, you would configure HTTP/HTTPS directly in Tomcat, usually in a configuration file called `server.xml`. For example:

```
<Connector port="8080"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="2000"
           minSpareThreads="10"
           maxThreads="100"/>
```

You can also package a Spring Boot application as a standalone JAR artifact for which the [web server is embedded](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-embedded-container), it's part of the application itself, so you can run as a standard Java app like `java -jar myapp.jar`. In this case, any Tomcat configuration would happen through Spring Boot, either from a property file (`application.properties` or `application.yml`) or through a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean. For example:

```
server:
  port: 9001
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 2000
    threads:
      max: 100
      min-spare: 10
```

In both scenarios, the HTTP configuration is meant for Tomcat, since that's the component "speaking" the HTTP protocol and responding to the clients. Spring Boot provides a nice and convenient interface to configure the server. The same is true for HTTPS. The choice between the two depends on your architecture. If you're using Spring Boot with the embedded server, than you would add the HTTPS configuration through Spring properties or beans. If you're interested in how to do that, I wrote an [article](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/) about it.

In the pairs you mentioned, there are always some common elements:

- a web server managing HTTP connections
- an application interacting with the web server to get HTTP requests and reply with HTTP responses.

The interaction between the two varies depending on languages, frameworks, and servers. In the case of Tomcat, the server has two main components: the one responsible for managing HTTP (called Coyote in Tomcat) and the one providing an execution context for a Java application to run and interact with the server (called Catalina in Tomcat). The interaction between a Java application and Tomcat happens according to the Java Servlet API.